# Cannot get crosswalk HelloWorld example to work

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to get a simple crosswalk HelloWorld app to build but am running into problems (app doesn't start in the emulator). This is the tutorial I am following.
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/develop_an_application.html

The only thing I did differently was to download the arm version (crosswalk-cordova-11.40.277.7-arm) as that is what I wish to target.

The output of "adb logcat > adb.log" when trying to run the app. http://pastebin.com/xWJreNzC

Log lines containing "HelloWorld".

```
$ grep -n HelloWorld adb.log 
1515:W/ActivityManager(  389): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/HelloWorld-debug-unaligned.apk
1576:W/ActivityManager(  389): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/HelloWorld-debug-unaligned.apk
1853:I/ActivityManager(  389): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.crosswalkproject.sample/.HelloWorld} from pid 1018
1866:I/ActivityManager(  389): Start proc org.crosswalkproject.sample for activity org.crosswalkproject.sample/.HelloWorld: pid=1029 uid=10052 gids={50052, 3003}
1903:I/ActivityManager(  389): Displayed org.crosswalkproject.sample/.HelloWorld: +3s818ms
2075:W/InputDispatcher(  389): channel 'b2fcec00 org.crosswalkproject.sample/org.crosswalkproject.sample.HelloWorld (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2076:E/InputDispatcher(  389): channel 'b2fcec00 org.crosswalkproject.sample/org.crosswalkproject.sample.HelloWorld (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2080:I/WindowState(  389): WIN DEATH: Window{b2fcec00 u0 org.crosswalkproject.sample/org.crosswalkproject.sample.HelloWorld}
2081:W/ActivityManager(  389): Force removing ActivityRecord{b2f6d828 u0 org.crosswalkproject.sample/.HelloWorld t2}: app died, no saved state
2082:W/InputDispatcher(  389): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'b2fcec00 org.crosswalkproject.sample/org.crosswalkproject.sample.HelloWorld (server)'
```

The avd being used

```
$ android list avd
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: android-19
  Device: 3.2in HVGA slider (ADP1) (Generic)
    Path: /home/fabe/.android/avd/android-19.avd
  Target: Android 4.4.2 (API level 19)
 Tag/ABI: default/armeabi-v7a
    Skin: HVGA
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Issue was resolved by enabling "Use host GPU" for the avd.

The following log entry hinted at his being the problem.

1908: F/chromium( 1029): [FATAL:gl_surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)