# Stop running the program because WebView

Tags: xamarin.android, android-webview

My program runs successfully and the simulator runs, but all at once end.
An error occurs on this:
mWebView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("", str1, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

```
    WebView mWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
    String str1 =
                "<html>" +
                      "<head>" +
                            "<style type='text/css'>" +
                                 "@font-face {font-family:SFont; src:url('file:///android_asset/fonts/MyFont.TTF');}" +
                                 "@font-face {font-family:TFont; src:url('file:///android_asset/fonts/times.ttf');}" +
                                            "Ptext {" +
                                                "font-family: SFont;" +
                                                "font-size: 19px;" +
                                                "text-align: justify;" +
                                            "}" +
                                                "Etext {" +
                                                "font-family: TFont;" +
                                                "font-size: 13px;" +
                                                "text-align: justify;" +
                                            "}" +
                                          "body {" +
                                            "text-align: justify;" +
                                               "}" +
                            "</style>" +
                      "</head>" +
              "<body dir = rtl>" +
              "<font style='opacity:0.79'>" +
               "<font color='white'>" +
                 "<Ptext>" + "Hello Hello" + " " + "</Ptext>" +

                  "<Etext>" + "Hello Hello" + "</Ptext>" +
                  "</font>" +
             "</body>" +
       "</html>";

    mWebView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#00000000"));
    mWebView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("", str1, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

ERRORS:

`[ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(327)] No suitab EGL configs found.`
`[ERROR:gl_surface_egl_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff faild.`
`[Error:browser_main_lppo.cc(698)]GLSurdace::InitializeOneOff faild`
`[FATAL:gl_Surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation()(0 vs. 0)`

Comment: Is there any error message? I tried your code and no error occurs on my side.

Comment: Please look at the errors

Comment: Webview is the cause of the problem, why?

Comment: Are you testing in emulator? Can you please try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235649/cannot-get-crosswalk-helloworld-example-to-work)?

Comment: With Use Host GPU, my problem could not be solved.

Comment: Can you please share the full logs? Full stacktrace?

Comment: Hello and thank you. It is about 1700 lines, of course before `mWebView.LoadDataWithBaseURL`.
After `mWebView.LoadDataWithBaseURL`, the program terminates quickly and I see fatal error `[FATAL:gl_Surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation()(0 vs. 0)`.
How do I put these 1700 lines?

Comment: I'm  testing an Android 10 emulator. Can you try on another device? The error log does not help much you shared.

Comment: I asked my friend to test my program on his mobile and the program answered correctly, but In my simulator, which has Android 6, gives this error.

Comment: Do you really need to support Android 6, it's a quite old version. The error seems caused by the old emulator does not support some feature. See [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37065041) may help.

Comment: Hello. I am adding Android 7 to the platforms to see if my problem is solved.

Comment: Yes, you can share your solution here if you solved it.

Comment: Hello. If I can install and use Android 7, I will put the result.